# priority_queue::emplace calls push_heap?

Tags: c++, performance, priority-queue, emplace

According to [CPP Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/emplace), `std::priority_queue::emplace` "effectively calls"

```
c.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
std::push_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
```

What does "effectively" mean here?  Does it mean `emplace` has the same functionality as those calls, or that `emplace` is literally implemented using those calls (my understanding is that the implementation is left to the compilers).  If `emplace` is literally implemented that way, isn't that inefficient?  If I add one element to an existing heap, I shouldn't need to heapify the entire heap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation certainly doesn't have to call the algorithm but probably it does. After `emplacing()` the element it will be move towards the root until the heap invariant is restored. Note that `push_heap()` does *not* touch the entire heap: that would be `make_heap()`. Instead, `push_heap()` deals only with adding one new element.

Comment: Oops, dumb question.  Thanks.